# Procv sem o ultimo caractere

Tags: microsoft-excel, procv

Tenho um `procv`, onde escrevi o seguinte:

```
SE(ÉERROS(PROCV($A2;'PLAN2'!$A:$C;1;0));"Não Encontrado";"Encontrado")
```

Funciona muito bem em casos exatos de procura de valores, mas alguns casos fugiram da normalidade, como por exemplo, quando no valor procurado tenho `AST-12236158A` e na tabela tenho `AST-12236158`, neste caso o valor não é encontrado por conta do último caractere, que aparentemente é sempre alfabético, uma letra A, B ou C.

Desta forma preciso efetuar a busca suprimindo o último caractere, e não tenho como simplesmente colocar a quantidade de caracteres na formula, como vi em um vídeo, pois não são constantes a quantidade deles.

Tentei o código abaixo, mas não funciona porque o número de caracteres não é sempre 12.

```
=PROCV(DIREITA(A2;12)*1;'PLAN2'!$A:$C;1;FALSO)
```

O que preciso é que em caso de erro, seja efetuada uma segunda verificação suprimindo o último caractere. Acredito que na segunda verificação, será melhor utilizar um `Localizar`, último caractere e suprimi-lo do `Procv`.

Comment: Olhando por cima seu problema eu sugiro criar uma nova coluna e referenciar à coluna onde você faz a busca, com uma fórmula que elimine o último caractere caso tenha mais de 12. Depois você faz o `procv ` direto nesta coluna criada e normalizada em 12 caracteres.

Answer (score -2):

=SE(SEERRO(DIREITA(A2;1)*1;0)=0;PROCV(ESQUERDA(A2;NÚM.CARACT(A2)-1);$I:$J;2;0);PROCV(A2;$I:$J;2;0))

Esta fórmula avalia se o ultimo caractere é numeral ou não, caso não possa mexer na sua base.

Comment: Obrigado vou verificar na planilha, havia recebido uma sugestão de outra fonte e utilizei conforme abaixo, adicionando algumas verificações extras: =SE($Z2<>"Haroldo";"";SE($L2="FD/DE Não Encontrado";"";SE(ÉERROS(PROCV($C2;'Tags x FDs e DEs'!$B:$I;7;0));PROCV(ESQUERDA($C2;NÚM.CARACT($C2)-1);'Tags x FDs e DEs'!$B:$I;7;0);PROCV($C2;'Tags x FDs e DEs'!$B:$I;7;0))))